# adding more data elements to Chartjs tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, chart.js, donut-chart

I'm using chartjs to make doughnut charts and am curious on how to add additional elements to a tooltip.  My code is below:

```
  var a = []; 
    var b = [];
    var f = [];  
    var u = [];
    for(var i =0; i < c.data.list.length; i++) {
        a.push(c.data.list[i].ptoType);
        b.push(c.data.list[i].hours);
        f.push(c.data.list[i].color);
        u.push(c.data.list[i].expDate); 
    }

    $scope.date = u;
    $scope.labels = a;
    $scope.colors= f;
    $scope.slice = b;
    $scope.options = {cutoutPercentage: 80,
                    responsive: true};

<canvas id="donut" class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-data="slice" chart-options="options" chart-labels="labels" chart-colors="colors">
          </canvas>
```

Currently my tool tip just shows the labels (array a) and the value of the slice (array b).  However, I would like to add Expiration Date as another element in the tool tip (array u).  How would I do this? Thanks!